# Why does my php wordpress show the_tags is showing the word array?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the I'm using to get the tags of each blog posts on wordpress

```
<?php the_tags( array(
    'title_li' => '',
) ); ?>
```

The result is

> ArrayTag1

I am wanted to remove the word `Array` so only the tag can be seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi its because you are doing it wrong please check this page [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags)

```
 the_tags( $before, $sep, $after );
```

$before is not a array and you wrote it as a array so its using array() as a text.

Comment: Thanks this is my new command `<?php the_tags(''); ?>` and it worked